# Enhanced Rich Text field via a schema.xml

Tags: sharepoint-2010, schema, listitem

I am trying to create an enhanced rich text field using a schema.xml. Currently I have the following:

```
 <Field ID="8EE65A51-1427-4D5A-8DD0-3712BE5991F0" Name="AudioLinks" 
 DisplayName="AudioLinks" Type="Note" NumLines="1"  RichText="TRUE" 
 Description="Audio Link URL."/>
```

The above creates a Rich Text field.

How would I go about creating that into an Enhanced Rich Text field instead?

Stuck with this for over a day now. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try setting the RichTextMode attribute to FullHtml:

```
<Field ID="8EE65A51-1427-4D5A-8DD0-3712BE5991F0"
    Name="AudioLinks"
    DisplayName="AudioLinks"
    Type="Note"
    NumLines="1"
    RichText="TRUE"
    RichTextMode="FullHtml"
    Description="Audio Link URL."/>
```

For more information see:

- [Field Element (List)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms437580.aspx)
- [Creating an Enhanced Rich Text Field in your SharePoint Content Types](http://leedale.wordpress.com/2009/01/20/creating-an-enhanced-rich-text-field-in-your-sharepoint-content-types/)